# Unable to add MACM Service in Bluemix Space

Tags: mobile, content-management-system, ibm-cloud

On clicking Create button, I am getting the below error in a dialog:

> Service broker error: {“description”=>”Failed creating service instance"}

The below is the screenshot:

[image: Bluemix Add Service Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it was a temporary problem. The service appears to be up now and I could create successfully the service either in US-South or in EU-GB region.
Please try to recreate the service now.

Comment: I tested again after posting the question, its working now.